# Informix Server - 5 databases with same name

Tags: informix

( Original question changed 12/21/22 - had wrong Informix server name - Should be Informix Dynamic Server )

I have 5 different regional databases running on one machine using Informix SE that I now must move to Informix Dynamic Server (IDS). All 5 databases have the same name, but are stored in completely different directories. It is a business requirement that each database is kept separate.

---

Some database/code information

Code is over 20 years old, but has been continuously updated to meet changing business needs.

There are over 200 tables.

Each of the 5 databases maintains over 4 million records with retention being 1 year for most tables.

Running on 1 Solaris server, the performance has been great.

The code base contains 45 4ge modules made up of 286 4gl modules.

There are over 200 reports now converted from ace to 4gl as well.

So, renaming the database would require changing almost 500 4gl modules.

---

Having maintained the SE databases for 20 years, I am now being required to set up the IDS database with no previous experience in it.

The question now: is there some straight forward documentation on how to set up multiple instances of IDS to support the 5 separate regional databases?

Comment: Ummmm, what do you mean by Informix Online?  I guess is Inforix Dynamic Server (IDS) as I doubt Online is supported (or avaiable) anymore. 
If is IDS, I'm pretty sure you can't do that, as the database name has to be unique within an IDS instance (server).  In theory you could create 5 different IDS instances (like 5 SE servers) each one with one database (same name for all) and then you do "db1@server1", or "db1@server2", but its definitly not ideal.

Comment: @jsagrera is correct about the term "Informix OnLine 5.x" — you should not be using that for a database migration now.  It would be one thing if you'd been using it for the last quarter of a century, but it should not be used for new deployments.  With that said, moving from SE is a good idea.  You just need to target using the correct system — Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) 14.10.

Comment: Your best bet is to use five different database names in one Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) instance.  You would have to modify the code to connect to the correct database.  You could consider using "tenant databases", but that may be a bit more complex than you want.  Alternatively, have 5 separate instances of IDS and the same database name in each, but that's less ideal.  It uses more system memory to limited advantage — you'd getter better use of the memory with a single instance.  Do you have control over the application code?  That will be a factor to think about.

Comment: With Genero, this issue would be addressed with concept of indirect database specification.  DATABASE foo, or (CONNECT TO foo) would look up the entry for "foo" in a configuration file which would contain the details to point at the actual physical database (which did not need to be named "foo").  That meant your 4gl code did not need to be modified or recompiled in order to point to a different physical database. Instead you could change environment variable to indicate a different config file and hence a different physical database.   Continued ...

Comment: ... continued. Link to Genero doc on indirect database specification http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#fgl-topics/c_fgl_Connections_014.html. Just as Jonathan says that moving from SE to IDS is a good idea, recompiling your 4gl code using Genero would also be seen as a good idea particularly as you say "Code is over 20 years old, but has been continuously updated to meet changing business needs". You will no doubt find some things that 4gl holds you back on that has been incorporated into Genero over the years, same as SE vs IDS.